# GCD of two polynomials

Tags: java

In the code below I want to find Greatest Common Divisor of 2 polynomials.
Sometimes I am getting error on " return c.plus( (a.minus(b.times(c)).divides(b)) );". How can I fix it?

```
public Polynomial divides(Polynomial b) {
Polynomial a = this;

        if ((b.deg == 0) && (b.coef[0] == 0))
            throw new RuntimeException("Divide by zero polynomial"); 

        if (a.deg < b.deg) return new Polynomial(0,0);

        int coefficient = a.coef[a.deg]/(b.coef[b.deg]);

        int exponent = a.deg - b.deg;
        Polynomial c = new Polynomial(coefficient, exponent);
        return c.plus( (a.minus(b.times(c)).divides(b)) );
    }

 public Polynomial GCD(Polynomial b) {
            Polynomial a = this;
            Polynomial f = b;
            Polynomial x = a.minus((a.divides(f)).times(f));

            if (x.deg == 0 && x.coef[0] == 0) {
                return b;
            }
            return f.GCD(x);

        }
```

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Answer (score 0):

That runtime exception means: you created an endless recursion.

Most likely, because your method *divides()* is calling itself on that last row - without proper checking in there to avoid that recursion.

In other words: you want to review your maths and the logic in there to simply avoid that *divides()* keeps calling itself without any limits!